# Problema na extração de texto usando PDFReader API

Tags: php

Estou mexendo com a [classe PDFreader](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=641) para fazer a extração do texto de um documento PDF.
Fiz um documento bem simples para fazer um teste onde somente dou include no arquivo `PDFreader.class.php` e passei o caminho do PDF com a chamada citada no arquivo de exemplo dentro da pasta `examples`.

Quando tento rodar esse arquivo para me retornar o texto do PDF aparece o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: Font in C:\setti\www\dg\t2\PDFreader\PDFpage.class.php on line 317

Segue o código que esta no meu arquivo:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<body>
<?php
include ('PDFreader.class.php');

$PDF = new PDFreader();
try {
    $PDF->open('t1t.pdf');
    $text = $PDF->readText();
}
catch(PDFexception $e) {
    echo '<p style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">';
    echo "$e</p>\n";
}

echo "<h2>Decoded text</h2>
<p>\n";
foreach ($text as $row) {
    echo "$row<br />\n";
}
echo "</p>\n";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Como consertar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código que você postou funciona no OS X. No site do *package* [vemos o seguinte](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=641):

> [image: Dependencies: Linux (May work on Windows, but untested)]

Ênfase minha: ***Pode ser que funcione em Windows***.
E sendo a última atualização de 2010, acho que funcionar no seu sistema (`C:\`) vai ser... complicado.

Opções:

[Fazendo esta busca](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bphp%5D%20pdf%20parser), encontrei uma Q&A no Stack Overflow com várias sugestões: [Is there a PDF parser for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1251956/1287812). Além das respostas visiveis, há um par de deletadas cujos links podem ser úteis aqui:

- [Reading the "clean" text from PDF with PHP](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php)
- [php.net : PDF Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php)

Comment: Pois é, tava querendo um milagre pois tenho que arrumar alguma coisa para ler pdf logo, você teria algum que não seja o pdfparser???

Comment: @user1875730, atualizei a resposta com links úteis, boa sorte!